# Viewport keeps resizing on scroll

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, viewport

I'm new to the responsive designs and I've run into an odd problem with scrolling. It seems that every time I scroll, the viewport seems to keep re-sizing. I've tried using the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` with initial scale set to 1, but no use. I'm also using media queries.

I also did a test where I turned everything off and used jQuery to detect a re-size event using an alert. Zoomed in with pinch zoom and tried scrolling and got a viewport re-size alert. I also noticed that after I scroll, the scroll bar will flash twice in indication of a sizing event going on.

It seems as if I'm missing something in my setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to add this meta tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

Comment: have a look @https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mobile%2FViewport_meta_tag

Comment: @webkit Yes I did, but I'd rather not disable user scaling for users. Seems like it's happened before on multiple platforms (both iOS and Android). One suggestion I found stated that I should try checking the orientation, resize, and scroll properties using jQuery. I'm about to try that now.

Answer (score 0):

The viewport is indeed re-sizing because the browser bar hides or appears when you scroll.

If you are reliant on a "real" resize event you could check whether the width has changed.